# Unorthodox project structure results in ImportError of submodule after install

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils

The project I am working on has the following strucutre:

```
|- setup.py
|- package/
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- file_a.py
|  |- file_b.py
|  |- submodule/
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- submodule_part_a/
|  |  |  |- file_c.py
|  |  |- submodule_part_b/
|  |  |  |- file_d.py
```

When I run `from package.submodule.submodule_part_a import file_c` I receive the following Error: `ImportError: No module named 'package.submodule'`

After some research it seems that this is caused by either the `packages` or `package_dir`. The setuptools `setup` method in the `setup.py` file looks similar to this:

```
setup(..., packages=['package',], package_dir={'package':'package'}, ...)
```

I've confirmed that once the above package is installed there is no `submodule` folder inside the installed directory.

What needs to be done in order to correctly install `submodule`?

Comment: I think you don't need `package_dir` here. Just use [find_packages](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) to collect all packages automatically and make `submodule_part_a` and `submodule_part_b` proper packages by giving them `__init__.py` files.